# How to delete itab rows via range?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I have a main internal table `ITAB`:

[image]

I have casted the field `DATA_STRING` (with a pre-defined structure):

[image]

I have a range with one of the rows from above that needs to be deleted:

[image]

Code snippet:

```
LOOP AT itab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs1>).
 ASSIGN <fs1>-data_string TO <fs2> CASTING.
 IF <fs2>-number IN range[].
   DELETE ITAB from <fs1>.
 ENDIF. 
ENDLOOP.
```

This might be a dumb question but is there a way to access and delete the row from `ITAB` without going through the loop? Something like

```
DELETE itab where data_string-number IN range[].
```

Or is there a way to directly extract `DATA_STRING` field to `ITAB2` (image 2) without a loop?

Comment: Yes, It still shows too many pending edits and not allowing me to edit the post :(

Comment: Why don't you do it with patterns in a range? `CP` instead of `EQ` and `*123*` instead of `123`? You can also do the OpenSQL on internal tables. It has been there for some time already.

Comment: Using `CP` is worth a try but in my case its `KUNNR` values within a search help exit (`RECORD_TAB`). So I am trying to cast them into an actual structure rather than using string references in case there is a change in the search help structure in the future.

Comment: If it concerns a search help exit, then possibly you need to use `F4UT_PARAMETER_VALUE_GET` (parameter `FIELDNAME = '*'` to get all components). I think it's best to continue focusing on your initial question without reference to the search help. Otherwise, better ask a new question concerning search help exit.

Comment: True, I am still curious about " is there a  simpler way to directly extract DATA_STRING field from ITAB to ITAB2 (image 2) without a loop?"

Answer (score 1):

If the range is filled correctly, it should work like this:

```
DELETE itab WHERE number IN range.
```

Full working simple:

```
RANGES: lr_matkl  FOR t023-matkl.
DATA: lt_t023 TYPE TABLE OF t023.
DATA: lt_mara TYPE TABLE OF mara.

SELECT * UP TO 10 ROWS
  FROM t023
  INTO TABLE lt_t023.

SELECT *
  FROM mara
  INTO TABLE lt_mara.

LOOP AT lt_t023 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_matkl>) WHERE matkl <> space.
  lr_matkl-sign   = 'I'.
  lr_matkl-option = 'EQ'.
  lr_matkl-low    = <fs_matkl>-matkl.
  APPEND lr_matkl.
ENDLOOP.

CHECK lr_matkl IS NOT INITIAL.
DELETE lt_mara WHERE matkl IN lr_matkl.
```

Answer (score 1):

With a dynamic internal table (structure of lines unknown at compile time), you may use a [dynamic condition with `DELETE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapdelete_itab_lines.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_5@5@) since at least ABAP 7.02, e.g.:

```
DELETE itab WHERE (`component = 'value'`).
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS <table> TYPE ANY TABLE.
TYPES ty_airlines TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF scarr-carrid WITH EMPTY KEY.
TYPES ty_range_airlines TYPE RANGE OF scarr-carrid.

DATA(airlines) = VALUE ty_airlines( ).
ASSIGN airlines TO <table>.

airlines = VALUE #( ( 'AA' ) ( 'AF' ) ( 'LH' ) ).
DATA(range_airlines) = VALUE ty_range_airlines( ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = 'AF' ) ).

DELETE <table> WHERE ('table_line IN range_airlines').

ASSERT airlines = VALUE ty_airlines( ( 'AA' ) ( 'LH' ) ).
```

NB: the code is using [`table_line`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenpseudo_component_glosry.htm), but that's not related to the question (you may of course use component names of the internal table if the lines are structured, e.g. `data_string-number` in the case of the OP question).